# I can't understand the error in the transform menu

Tags: jquery, menu

When I click on the **MENU**, the left pane is called and the **MENU** word is transformed into the word **EXIT**.

When I click **EXIT**, the left pane closes and the word **EXIT converts to MENU**. I want the left pane to close and the **EXIT** word to transform to **MENU** when I click the link, the button in that left pane. But I'm doing something wrong, because when I click the link in the **EXIT** pane and the **MENU** goes crazy. Help me figure this out. Here's the work code:

```js
"use strict";
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toggle-nav, a.button').on('click', function () {
            toggleNavigation($(this), $('.nav-pane'));
            changeLetters($(this));
        });
        function toggleNavigation(btn, nav) {
            btn.toggleClass('open');
            nav.toggleClass('open');
        }
        function changeLetters(btn) {
            var m = $('.toggle-nav span.m');
            var e = $('.toggle-nav span.e');
            var n = $('.toggle-nav span.n');
            var u = $('.toggle-nav span.u');
            e.toggleClass('btn-close');
            if (btn.hasClass('open')) {
                m.text("E");
                n.text("I");
                u.text("T");
            }
            else {
                m.text("M");
                n.text("N");
                u.text("U");
            }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-pane {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-350px);
          transform: translateX(-350px);
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 348px;
  background: #EA5548;
  border-right: 2px solid #e94d3f;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .nav-pane {
    width: 298px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-300px);
            transform: translateX(-300px);
  }
}
.nav-pane h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F1F1F1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.nav-pane.open {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
}

.toggle-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  right: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #212121;
}
.toggle-nav.open span.m, .toggle-nav.open span.n, .toggle-nav.open span.u {
  opacity: 1;
}
.toggle-nav span.m, .toggle-nav span.n, .toggle-nav span.u {
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.toggle-nav span.e {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 17px;
}
.toggle-nav span.e.btn-close span.bar:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 5px;
}
.toggle-nav span.e.btn-close span.bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
}
.toggle-nav span.e.btn-close span.bar:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 5px;
}
.toggle-nav span.e span.bar {
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: #212121;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #616161;
  width: 15px;
  height: 1px;
}
.toggle-nav span.e span.bar:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.toggle-nav:hover span.m, .toggle-nav:hover span.n, .toggle-nav:hover span.u {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 250ms;
  transition: 250ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Menu Toggle Effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="toggle-nav"><span class="m">M</span><span class="e"><span class="bar"></span><span class="bar"></span><span class="bar"></span></span><span class="n">N</span><span class="u">U</span></div>
<div class="nav-pane slide-out"><a class="button" href="#">Click me</a></div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
https://codepen.io/ukropossum/pen/GRpLwjE
```

Comment: because this is the link, not the menu. You are not going to find the letters when you are starting from the link.

Comment: @epascarello - sorry, I didn't get it. Can you explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggle-nav, a.button').on('click', function() {
     toggleNavigation($('.toggle-nav'), $('.nav-pane'));
      changeLetters($('.toggle-nav'));
    });
```

Comment: Explain your solution, stranger.